# MS Access Left Join Not Supported - Combobox as Variable

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have 3 tables used for tracking deviations to aircraft maintenance.

1 - Deviations - describes the deviation in place.

2 - Aircraft - A list of aircraft in the fleet

3 - Aircraft Deviations - columns with a unique ID, DeviationID, and AircraftID

I am trying to open a report, showing all the deviations against a specific aircraftID, using a combobox on a form to select the aircraft by ID.  I am using the combobox's onUpdate event to modify a query definition with the following SQL:

```
strSQL = "SELECT Deviation, Rev, Title, Issued, ExpiryDate, ExpiryHours, " _
& "ExpOther, Active FROM Deviations t1 LEFT JOIN " _
& "AircraftDeviations t2 ON t1.ID = t2.DeviationID " _
& "AND t2.AircraftID = " & Me!cmbAircraft
```

I am receiving a LEFT JOIN not supported error.  I have tried adding brackets and it goes through error free but I see everything in the table instead of just those by the specific aircraft number.  I have tested the statement by hardcoding in the aircraftID I want (eg: 428) but I still get the join not supported error with the "AND t2.AircraftID = 428" highlighted.

Am I using the wrong join here?  What is the correct way of writing this query?

Comment: You need to use "WHERE" clause instead. So, "SELECT Deviation, ... t2 on t1.ID=t2.DeviationID WHERE td2.aircraftID=428"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that MS Access does not allow constants in the `ON` clause.  Alas.  This is just one of many awkward limitations in the Access version of SQL.

You can do what you want with a subquery, though:

```
SELECT Deviation, Rev, Title, Issued, ExpiryDate, ExpiryHours, 
       ExpOther, Active
FROM Deviations as d LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT ad.*
      FROM AircraftDeviations as ad
      WHERE ad.AircraftID = Me!cmbAircraft
     ) as ad
     ON d.ID = ad.DeviationID ;
```

EDIT:

If you want an inner join, then the code is even simpler:

```
SELECT Deviation, Rev, Title, Issued, ExpiryDate, ExpiryHours, 
       ExpOther, Active
FROM Deviations as d INNER JOIN 
     AircraftDeviations as ad
     ON d.ID = ad.DeviationID
WHERE ad.AircraftID = Me!cmbAircraft;
```

The subquery is only needed because of the `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Tried this, unfortunately it still retrieves all the records in the deviations table instead of just those with the aircraft number.

Comment: Got it to work, took a shot in the dark and used your suggestion along with changing it to INNER JOIN instead of LEFT.

Comment: "MS Access does not allow constants in the ON clause" -- by 'constant' do you mean 'literal value'? If so then this is a very awkward truth!

Comment: @onedaywhen . . . Yes, I do mean "literal value" -- and that is the official name in SQL.  However, I think "constant" is more easily understood by more people, which is why I often use that instead.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: this almost never happens, but I think you're wrong here. One *can* use constants / literals in `ON` clauses, if parentheses are put around it. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/15c36745-f7a4-4926-9687-7161e5894468/join-expression-not-supported-error-caused-by-unbracketed-join-expression-comprising-string?forum=accessdev